# I have a trouble running nimbus apache storm 2.0.0 on windows

Tags: apache-storm

In Apache storm 2.0.0  when I run nimbus, it stops after a while. The error message is:

```
java.lang.Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni4098681609019942941.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

In Storm 1.2.3 I did not have this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't have the MSVC library installed that Rocksdb needs on Windows. Please see https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksJava-Basics#maven. You probably need to go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 and install that.

Answer (score 0):

you should run  Apache Storm in by administrator user In windows 10. So, I entered to system as administrator and the problem was solved.